# NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER expected : (colon)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios7

I am trying to declare a designated initializer like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id <MyDelegate>)delegate NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

But it is showing me this compilation error:

```
Expected ':'
```

Interestingly when I try to write it like this (reference link: [Adopting Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html)) -

```
- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

It shows this error:

```
Expected ';' after method prototype.
```

Any ideas on how to properly use NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER?

Comment: if you `cmd` + click on `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER`, what does it give you?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` macro is not defined in the library headers for Xcode 5 - you need Xcode 6 to use it. Note your link says "Pre-release".

The macro is defined in the following way (quoting `NSObjCRuntime.h`)

```
#ifndef NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#if __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
#else
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#endif
#endif
```

Note you can still use

```
- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id <MyDelegate>)delegate __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer));
```

in Xcode 5 or you can add that macro explicitly to your precompiled header.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind you can only add this to interface or class extension declarations otherwise you'll get this error:

```
'objc_designated_initializer' attribute only applies to init methods of interface or class extension declarations
```